# Git pull is not working in my local machine

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-pull

I am using redhat Linux server in VMWare.

I created a repository in github. And trying to git push after cloning it to my local repository after all setup. I added and committed a file now time to push a file to remote repo.

Whenever I do git push it's showing like that, I mean I'm getting 403 error page. And showing https.github.com/reponame/repo/info/refs   (can not access the url)

Here the thing is in url info/refs added to my remote repo link that's why it's not accepting to git push. Don't know why it's added.

And here I noticed that git pull origin master working properly.

Answer (score 0):

While I have no idea how you managed to get 'info/refs' into the url, but I know how you can fix it. You can change the origin remote url by running

```
`git remote set-url origin "https://github.com/<username>/<project-name>"`
```

Make sure to change  and  to your requirements and you should be good to go.